# Initial value of <select> tag in React.js+Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple component that renders `select` tag and synchronizes selected value with the state:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  onChange = (event) => {
    this.props.updateValue("value", event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    const {value} = this.props;
    return <div>
      <label>
        <span>Select smth</span>
        <select name="select" value={value} onChange={this.onChange}>
          <option value="1">First</option>
          <option value="2">Second</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
    </div>;
  }
}

export default connect(state => {value: state.value}, {updateValue: actions.updateValue})(App)
```

My problem that at the first render, the value coming from the store is empty. However when I am checking value with `document.querySelector('[name="select"]').value` it shows me some value. So my UI state is out of sync with store state. When later user will submit the form, the value will not be sent.

How can I *always* keep select value in sync with Redux store state?

See the full code at CodePen: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObxNPp?editors=0010

**UPD.** The actual code also uses Redux. Updated code sample to show that. Setting initial value will not work because store doesn't know anything about available options.

Comment: Try set default state value - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVzOrW?editors=0010

Comment: Actually in my real code that state belongs to Redux store. Not sure that I can set default state there, because it doesn't know available options.

Comment: you can set default state in reducer

Comment: How default state will know, which one is the default, when it is contained only in UI? I expected, that react will do this for me, as it does, when form is being autocompleted by browser, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Set your state to the be the correct value at the beginning:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqPZva

```
state = {
  value: this.props.value
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App value="2" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### Update based upon comments:

```
state = {
  value: this.props.options[0].value
};
```

Comment: That would be easy if I knew which one is the default. Currently, the select is always a source of initial value. How can I grab initial value after select was rendered?

Comment: @just-boris Is your select element being generated from data or is it just hard-coded like in your example?

Comment: I am generating options like the following `<select>{this.props.options}</select>`. Those values are coming from some external source, backend, for instance

Comment: does `this.props.options` contain the html, or does it contain an array of data that is then turned into HTML via some other means?

Comment: This is an array of items, like `{value: "1", title: "First"}`

Comment: @just-boris See updated answer for a recommendation based upon what you just said. Pen updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqPZva

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state for the `<select>` tag is not set properly. You need to set:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 1
  };
  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  };

  render() {
    const {value} = this.state;
    return <div>
      <label>
        <span>Select smth</span>
        <select name="select" value={value} onChange={this.onChange}>
          <option value="1">First</option>
          <option value="2">Second</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Since the value of `value` is undefined as per your initial state, the select menu is not given a selected value which results in the first option being rendered as selected by the browser which is the default behavior of the drop-down menu in the browser.

Check out this forked [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBGZXO?editors=0010) for clarity.

Comment: See update. How can I set initial value into Redux store? Also in some cases that value comes from server and should not be overridden

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you didn't assign any value to your state variable "value". put a console `console.log('value', value)` after `const {value} = this.state;` you will see the value is undefined. when you are checking the value with `document.querySelector('[name="select"]').value`, it is giving you the value of select not the state variable, once you are changing the dropdown, state variable receives a value after this everything will work proper. State variable value will be undefined until you change the dropdown.
since the state value is undefined, select rendered the first element.

Assign a proper value to your state variable :

```
state = {
   value: 1 or 2,
};
```

Comment: See update. Actually, state belongs to Redux store, so I can't arbitrary set default value. Store still will keep empty value.